# Error when sending Outbound Message

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage

I need to create a record for custom object in Org1. Then by using outbound messaging, I am trying to get all the details of each record created in Org1 to get created in Org2 with same data.
I am getting this error while trying to send an Outbound Message from a workflow:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog
```

Please suggest possible solutions.

Comment: What URL did you put in the OM config to get it to goto org2? why don't you just use salesforce 2 salesforce?

Comment: That particular error message normally indicates that either the response isn't XML when it should be, or it has leading white space in it, which isn't allowed.